# Computing double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $$\int^{1}_{0} f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{2}$$ compute $$\int_{0}^{1} \int^{1}_{x} f(x)f(y) \ \mathrm{d}y \ \mathrm{d}x$$

First I change the order of integration: $$\int_{?}^{?} \int^{?}_{?} f(x)f(y) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y$$ but what happens to the limits? What do I change them to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw a picture. The region $$\{(x,y):0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\;,\;x\leqslant y\leqslant 1\}$$ is the same region as $$\{(x,y):0\leqslant y\leqslant 1\;,\;0\leqslant x\leqslant y\}$$

Comment: How do you draw a picture? I don't know what $f$ is

Comment: @user2850514 Draw the region of integration, my point is.

Answer (score 3):

Setting
$$
F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\int_x^1f(x)f(y)\,dxdy&=&\int_0^1f(x)\left(\int_x^1f(y)\,dy\right)\,dx
=\int_0^1f(x)(F(1)-F(x))\,dx\\
&=&F(1)\int_0^1f(x)\,dx-\int_0^1f(x)F(x)\,dx
=(F(1))^2-\int_0^1F'(x)F(x)\,dx\\
&=&(F(1))^2-\frac12\left[(F(x))^2\right]_0^1
=(F(1))^2-\frac12(F(1))^2\\
&=&\frac12(F(1))^2
=\frac12(\sqrt{2})^2=1.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

> $$ \int_{0}^{1} \int^{y}_{0} f(x)f(y) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y $$

**Added:** Here is the region

[image]

Comment: How does this help the OP? There's no explanation whatsoever...

Comment: Perhaps it should be explained, rather than simply asserting that this is the result of interchanging limits.